# How to refactor laravel application code effectively

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm in a position to refactor my laravel 5.4 app codes due to some problems: Code complexity, lack of oo design experience etc.

I have read that controller codes should be as short as possible (it is claimed that they are glue code parts).

Q1: I have some library like codes. These library functions/classes should be in the related Model classes, or should I have extra classes which make use of Model classes?

Q2: If I don't need extra classes (so model classes are enough), should I call these business logics from blade files, or from controllers? (Business logics in controllers make them quite large and complex).

Example: In a controller function, I evaluate post dataset with a query. After that I need some business logic for each post like `effectiveValueOfPost($post)`. Should I call it from controller and pass it to the related view, or call it from blade file.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to provide the related code for your example?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to start refactoring my whole Laravel application according to the latest standards today itself. Here is how an Ideal Laravel application should be structured or created.

**Note:** These are not the hard rules but it will be easier to maintain your Laravel applications for future updates if you structure it this way.

**Controllers:**
Controllers should have these methods to Create, Read, Update and Destroy a specific model. To make it simple, Let's say our model is **Product**:

- index() - It will return the list of products.
- create() - It will show a form to create a model. (If required)
- store() - It will store product information coming from a create form.
- show() - It will return a specific product.
- edit() - It will show a form to edit any product.
- update() - It will update any specific product.
- destroy() - It will delete a specific product.

**Routes:** Routes will follow the same pattern for different models. Here are the routes that will call above given functions in the controller for a specific model, in this case, products.

- /products - GET - ProductController@index
- /products/create - GET - ProductController@create
- /products - POST - ProductController@store
- /products/{id} - GET - ProductController@show
- /products/{id}/edit - GET - ProductController@edit
- /products/{id} - PATCH - ProductController@update
- /products/{id} - DELETE - ProductController@destroy

**Models**: Now, all everything that deals with the database (Queries, complex queries, relations) will be stored in your Model (app/Product.php, in this case). There are no specified functions that you can use in Model. So, you can put all your queries and processing data from queries will be stored as functions in Model.

**Views**: The most basic model will require `create`, `edit`, `index` and `show` views. Inside **views** directory, you can create different directories for different models. In this case, there will be a directory called **products** inside **views** directory and it would contain all the above-given views as well as extra views that it might need.

I have worked on some really complex applications in Laravel. And this is the structure I follow to avoid any kind of confusion while creating or updating the application code. I don't even have to remember a random name that I gave to some view because everything is properly structured and totally based on the name of the controller.

Some controllers don't require all those routes and functions, in that case, you can still follow this method without being confused.

Comment: I’ve just stumbled across your answer while trying to find out the best routes to refactoring code. So I’ve built my first project with laravel and it all works. I just have a feeling some bits could be written better. Looking at what you’ve said if I understand correctly I shouldn’t have any other methods in my controller other than the basic crud ones? I have several methods in different controller should these be in my model then? Stuff like a user filters posts by date or categories which which then queries my DB.

Comment: @CIB You can use other methods in your controllers for sure. No worries about that. With this, you can only create CRUD applications but almost all applications has some edge that requires you to have many different methods in your controllers.